# OleDb Error Insert Statement contains the following unknown field name "Name"

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I created a program of C # code and find errors I've been many times have not been resolved .

```
string eksekusi = "INSERT INTO Table1([ID],[Name],[City]) VALUES ('01','Udin','Serang')";                
Console.WriteLine("------------------ EKSEKUSI ---------------------");
Console.WriteLine(eksekusi);
Console.WriteLine("------------------ RESULT ---------------------");
oledb.SET_QString(eksekusi);
if (oledb.SQL_Execute() == true)
    Console.WriteLine("Success..");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Error.. : "+oledb.Ret_ErrMsg);
```

> Error : Error Insert Statement contains the following unknown field name "Name"

Please help.

**Resolved** : Created new database in microsoft access 2010.

Comment: Have a look on the DB if the name of column `Name` is `Nama`

Comment: The error message given doesn't complain about the value inserted. It states that the field "Name" doesn't exist in your Table1.

Comment: is it `Nama` or `Name`? In insert query, you use `Name`

Comment: Have you typed Nama instead of Name?

Comment: Well, your edit changes things hugely...

Comment: Dbname is **Table1** and field **ID**, **Name**, and **City** and type TEXT

Comment: @WahyuKitech frankly, I'm going to default to assuming that the OleDb provider is right here, and that that Table1 it is finding does not have a Name column. If this was something like SQL Server, I'd say "check your schemas - is there a Table1 in a more local schema?" - not sure if access has schemas. So the other possibility is that you're connecting to a different database file than the one you're looking in. This is a very common error, especially when the database is in the /bin/debug or /bin/release folders

Comment: **oledb.SET_Cstring(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db1.accdb; Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = Whyoe162516amsja; ");**  --> connection string

Comment: @all thanks to all the friends who responded to my question

Answer (score 0):

Its highly likely that you dont have a column in your database which is called "Name".

And if you already have that column, you can delete it and create a new column called "Name" and move it to the appropriate location in the column list.

Comment: Can you share your table schema? May be the problem is arising at the database level

Comment: Resolved : Created new database microsoft access 2010.